# how to convert matrix operators in matlab to python

Tags: python, matlab, matrix, operations

I want to convert the following Matlab code to the equivalent in Python:

```
M.*((S*U)./max(realmin, M*(U'*U)))
```

where:

```
S: n*n
M: n*m
U: n*m
```

I have done it by the following code:

```
x = (max(-sys.maxint, np.matmul(M, np.matmul(np.transpose(U), U))))
M = np.dot(M, ((np.matmul(S, U)) / x))
```

but I got the following error:

```
x = (max(-sys.maxint, np.matmul(M, np.matmul(np.transpose(U), U))))
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is 
ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Would you please help me how I can convert the Matlab code to Python.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10062954/valueerror-the-truth-value-of-an-array-with-more-than-one-element-is-ambiguous

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10062954/valueerror-the-truth-value-of-an-array-with-more-than-one-element-is-ambiguous)

Comment: though the errors are the same but i think the problem for me is raised because of wrong conversion of matlab code and the privided links cannot help me

Comment: `M * ( S @ U) / np.maximum(numpy.finfo(float).tiny, M @ U.T @ U))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matlab's `max(a, b)` is a broadcasted elementwise maximum operation. Python's `max(a, b)` isn't. Python's `max` doesn't understand arrays, and you shouldn't use it on arrays.

For a broadcasted elementwise maximum, you want [`numpy.maximum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.maximum.html):

```
numpy.maximum(whatever, whatever)
```

Also, Matlab's `realmin` is the [smallest positive normalized double-precision floating-point number](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/realmin.html), while Python's `sys.maxint` is a [large negative int](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.maxint) (and also nonexistent on Python 3). That's probably not what you want. The equivalent to Matlab's `realmin` would be

```
sys.float_info.min
```

or

```
numpy.finfo(float).tiny
```

(`numpy.finfo(float).min` is a different thing.)

Comment: Would you please help me in correct conversion of the whole code?

Comment: what is the equivalent of ./ (right devision) in python?